# What is the difference between cgroup and none devices when mounting a cgroup?

Tags: linux, posix, mount, cgroups

On Ubuntu 22.04 with turned off cgroup v2 I see:

```
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
```

On Centos 9 Stream I see (no need to turn off cgroup v2 there, as cgroup v1 is also supported):

```
none on /run/cgroups/cpu type cgroup (rw,relatime,seclabel,cpu)
```

What is the difference between the `cgroup` device and `none` device in the context of using cgroups? If I see that cgroups are unmounted and I want to mount them, which device should I prefer, so that the code that mounts would work for the larger number of Linux distributions?